# android media player song not closing even i after closing application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

///////First Activity///////////

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
Button button;Button button3;MediaPlayer mp2;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.happy);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v)

            {

                Intent inent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
Main2Activity.class);

                startActivity(inent);



                if(mp2.isPlaying() == true)
{

                    mp2.pause();}


                else{

                    mp2.start();}

            }

        });



    }

}
```

/////////Second Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
Button button2;MediaPlayer mp2;




    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);






    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `onPause()` try this

```
mp2.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the first half of your question: you should get what you want if you call stopMediaPlayer() inside onPause() and onDestroy().

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopMediaPlayer();
}
```

or you can try this too,

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pause mediaplayer in `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` lifecycle methods.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onPause();
        mp2.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp2.pause();
    }
```